# Mysql Initializing Database error

Tags: mysql

**Initializing Database Error  [image]**

```
Error Log Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 5.7.21...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on...
mysqld: Character set '0.0' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\charsets\Index.xml' file
2018-04-02T09:44:47.468292Z 0 [Warning] option 'read_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 8192
2018-04-02T09:44:47.468337Z 0 [Warning] option 'read_rnd_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2018-04-02T09:44:47.468371Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-04-02T09:44:47.468381Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2018-04-02T09:44:47.469610Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Process for mysqld, with ID 11812, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
Failed to start process for MySQL Server 5.7.21.
Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing Database
```

Comment: So, can you edit your question and put an actual question in there? What part of the error log are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Please post your complete my.cnf-ini file for us to see what was created during the install.

Comment: Please edit your question to include posting your complete my.cnf-ini file for us to see what is being created for you during the install.  It appears read_buffer_size and read_rnd_buffer_size are the initial problems.  This file should be available on the server you were installing to after the failure.  It may be possible to edit the my.cnf-ini to get you past this startup problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when the selected port was already under use.
Changing the port (or stopping the existing service on that port) allowed me to continue from here.